# TFS Permissions

Tags: tfs, permissions, system

So, I'm running a TFS build that tests a class that manipulates TFS WorkItems. TFS runs as the SYSTEM user which has been added to the /Contributers permission group. However, the test suite fails with various invalid field errors (created by, Assigned to). Does any one know how to set the SYSTEM user up as a valid user?

Comment: How do you know that the SYSTEM user is _not_ a valid user?

Comment: Are all of the TFS components running on one machine? What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the SYSTEM account needs added to `Team Foundation Valid Users`

Answer (score -1):

configure build agent with a valid user or use a separate build user.